# About quotient of categories and free categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

**Preliminaries**:

Let $< Fr, \iota, \eta, \epsilon>: Cat\to Graph$ the usual adjunction involving the free category construction from a graph.  The cokernel of two functors   $F, G: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ (considering only small categories) is make by the following steps:

1) Let $q: \iota(\mathcal{B})\to I$ the cokernel of $\iota(F),\ \iota(G)$.

2) Let $\eta_I: I\to \iota(Fr(I))$

3) Consider the congruence on $Fr(I)$ generated by $q(g)\ast q(f) \sim q(g\circ f),\ q(1_X)\sim 1_X$ (where th second $1_X$ is the formal identity of the free category). Let $P: Fr(I)\to \mathcal{B}_q$ the quotient functor.

then (just because $(3))$  the graph morphism  $P\circ \eta_I\circ q$  is a functor,  formally $P\circ \eta_I\circ q=\iota({Q})$ with $Q: \mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{B}_q$, this is just the cokernel of the couple  $F, G$: if $H: \mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{C}$ with $H\circ F= H\circ G$ this get  a factorization  $H'': I\to \mathcal{C}$ on $q$, and then a a factorization  $H': Fr(I)\to \mathcal{C}$ on $\eta\circ q$, then $H'\circ (\eta\circ q) $ is a functor (it is $H$), and then we have a factorization on $P$. The unicity is obvious.

**End Preliminaries**

Generalizing what above let $<F, G, \eta,\ \epsilon>: \mathscr{C}\to \mathscr{D}$ and adjunction with $G$ faithful,  and let $q: B\to I$ a epimorphism. Define a morphism $h: B\to C$ $q$-*admissible*  if $G(h)$ factorizing (uniquely) by $q$, or equivalently (by adjunction) if there is a  (unique)  $h': F(I)\to C$ such that $G(h')\circ \eta_I\circ q= G(h)$. Consider the presheaf $C \mapsto (B, C)_q$ where $(B, C)_q$ is the set of $q$-admissible morphism from $B$ to $C$, this is isomorphic to $C\mapsto (F(I), C)^q$ where $(F(I), C)^q$ is the  set of morphism $ h': F(I)\to C$ such that $G(h')\circ \eta\circ q$ is equal to $G(h)$ for a (unique)  $h: B\to C$ (of course q-admissible).
The representability  of these presheaves  amount to a morphism  $P: GF(I)\to B_q$ that induce (by composition) a bijection $(F(I), C)_q \cong (B_q, C)$.

**I ask in what general conditions on $<F, G, \eta,\ \epsilon>: \mathscr{C}\to \mathscr{D}$ and $q$ we have that  the presheaf $C \mapsto (B, C)_q$ is representable**.